# ORA-00911: invalid character, visual studio 2010 using aspxgridview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, gridview

ive got this error when y try to insert a row in my oracle database.. im using the delete, insert function that are provided by aspxgridview.

ive heard that it could be a ";" at the end of the sql instructions but there is not ";" in this sql sentences, this is the code with the sql instructions for insert, update, etc...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
           ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringora %>" 
           DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM &quot;MAQUINA&quot; WHERE &quot;PATENTE&quot; = ? AND &quot;MARCA&quot; = ? AND &quot;MODELO&quot; = ? AND &quot;AÑO&quot; = ? AND &quot;FECHA_ADQUISICION&quot; = ? AND &quot;ESTADO&quot; = ? AND &quot;IDCONDUCTOR&quot; = ? AND &quot;IDMANTENCION&quot; = ?" 
           InsertCommand="INSERT INTO &quot;MAQUINA&quot; (&quot;PATENTE&quot;, &quot;MARCA&quot;, &quot;MODELO&quot;, &quot;AÑO&quot;, &quot;FECHA_ADQUISICION&quot;, &quot;ESTADO&quot;, &quot;IDCONDUCTOR&quot;, &quot;IDMANTENCION&quot;) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
           OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
           ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringora.ProviderName %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;PATENTE&quot;, &quot;MARCA&quot;, &quot;MODELO&quot;, &quot;AÑO&quot;, &quot;FECHA_ADQUISICION&quot;, &quot;ESTADO&quot;, &quot;IDCONDUCTOR&quot;, &quot;IDMANTENCION&quot; FROM &quot;MAQUINA&quot;" 
           UpdateCommand="UPDATE &quot;MAQUINA&quot; SET &quot;MARCA&quot; = ?, &quot;MODELO&quot; = ?, &quot;AÑO&quot; = ?, &quot;FECHA_ADQUISICION&quot; = ?, &quot;ESTADO&quot; = ?, &quot;IDCONDUCTOR&quot; = ?, &quot;IDMANTENCION&quot; = ? WHERE &quot;PATENTE&quot; = ? AND &quot;MARCA&quot; = ? AND &quot;MODELO&quot; = ? AND &quot;AÑO&quot; = ? AND &quot;FECHA_ADQUISICION&quot; = ? AND &quot;ESTADO&quot; = ? AND &quot;IDCONDUCTOR&quot; = ? AND &quot;IDMANTENCION&quot; = ?">
```

the other thing that i think it could cause this problem is the date field (FECHA_ADQUISICION).. aspxgridview uses the format dd-mm-yyy, i dont know if oracle accept that, because when i tried to make an insertion from the "server explorer" (that part where you can watch your databases) i had a problem with the date, i got "ORA-01843 not a valid month" error.. so i could not make an insertion from there.

help please!

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this is something to do with encodings.  What encoding is the XML document that contains the above in?  What encoding is your database connection using?  Do you get the same error if you remove the `AÑO` column from your SQL or rename the column to `ANO` (in your database as well as in your SQL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&quot;` is your problem. Replace it with single quote (`'`) and it will work.

**Updated:
Instead of hardcoding your sql queries, pass it from code behind. It will work. **

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but how would it look with the single quote (im a noob) ??!! LOL!
i tried not using &quot; at all one time.. i deleted all the "&quot;" from the sql sentences but i got the same error :(.

Comment: @LukeWoodward If you see the query in debugger you will see @quot; not " as @quot; is native to HTML not SQL.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  There are no `@quot;`s.  There are no `&quot;`s sent to the database as ASP.NET will replace then with `"`s.  As far as I can see the questioner's use of `&quot;` here is correct.